# Trivial join dependency

Tags: database, database-normalization

I'm having a difficulty to understand how to "work" with join dependencies, and I would like to ask a question that will help me clarify things for  myself.

Here's the simple definition from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_dependency):

> A table T is subject to a join dependency if T can always be recreated
>   by joining multiple tables each having a subset of the attributes of
>   T.

A trivial join dependency is defined as follows:

> If one of the tables in the join has all the attributes of the table
>   T, the join dependency is called trivial.

My question is: If we decompose a relation R into a lossless decomposition, is it possible that every join dependency of R could be a trivial join dependency?
An example would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If we decompose a relation R into a lossless decomposition, is it possible that the join dependency\ies of R would be a trivial join dependency\ies?

If you mean, if we decompose a relation R losslessly is it possible that all the JDs of R are trivial: yes.

*Whenever* all the JDs of R are trivial, you can decompose it losslessly, because by definition a JD is just a description of a lossless decomposition. And there are such relations. Every R, calling its attribute set S, satisfies the JDs *(S,S), *(S,S,S), etc. Some satisfy no other FDs. Some satisfy others but they're also trivial.

Eg: This R only satisfies *(S,S), *(S,S,S), etc:

```
x   y
1   2
5   2
5   4
```

Eg: Say S = {x,y} and FD {x}->{y} holds, so *({x},S} holds. But say JD *({x},{y}) doesn't hold. Then the only way a JD can have sets unioning to S is if S is one of them. So R has only trivial JDs. But not just the ones using only S.

```
x   y
1   2
5   2
6   4
```

If you mean, if we decompose a relation R losslessly *into smaller components* is it possible that all the JDs of R are trivial: no. Because by definition a trivial JD has one set that is all the attributes of R, ie has one component that is R, it doesn't decompose into components smaller than R.